# Checkbox Constantly Returns False?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm submitting a form using AJAX as follows:

```
$('#userUpdateForm').submit(function (e) {
            //var attachment = $('form#userUpdateForm').serialize();
            var blue = document.getElementById('blueCheck').checked;
            var personDetails = {
                Enabled: $('#eCheck').val(),
                Authorised: $('#authCheck').val(),
                Green: $('#greenCheck').val(),
                Blue: blue,
                //Blue: $('input[name="blueCheckbox"]').is(':checked'),
                Red: $('#redCheck').val(),
                Id: $('#idCheck').val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                //url: '<%= Url.Action("submitForm", "Home") %>',
                url: '@Url.Action("submitForm", "Home")',
                data: JSON.stringify({ jsonForm: personDetails}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("A problem occured when submitting the form.");
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

'Blue' refers to a checkbox. The form then submits to the controller HomeController/submitForm as below:

```
   public class updatePersonDetails
    {
        public string Enabled { get; set; }
        public string Authorised { get; set; }
        public string Green { get; set; }
        public bool Blue { get; set; }
        public string Red { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult submitForm(updatePersonDetails personDetails)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(personDetails.Blue.ToString());
        return View();
    }
```

But 'Blue' persistently returns 'False' when the checkbox has been checked and should return true. As you can see below, I have tried a variety of things to get the value:

```
        var attachment = $('form#userUpdateForm').serialize();
        var blue = document.getElementById('blueCheck').checked;
        Blue: $('input[name="blueCheckbox"]').is(':checked'),
```

What's even stranger is the jsonForm on the browser shows 'Blue:true' in the request payload. Is there something I'm missing from getting the proper value on the server side?

Edit: the HTML for the form

```
<form id="userUpdateForm" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Details</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="authorisedCheckbox" value="Authorised" id="authCheck" />Authorised<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="enabledCheckbox" value="Enabled" id="eCheck" />Enabled<br />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Favourite Colours</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="blueCheckbox" value="Blue" id="blueCheck" />Blue<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="greenCheckbox" value="Green" id="greenCheck" />Green<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="redCheckbox" value="Red" id="redCheck" />Red<br />
        <input type="hidden" name="personId" id="idCheck" value='@ViewData["personId"]'>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="Save Changes">
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

There's also a onload function to set the checkboxes to reflect the original data of the person, but I wouldn't have thought that would set the checkbox state as 'False' permanently.

```
    var blueVal = '@ViewData["blue"]';
    if (blueVal == "checked") {
        document.getElementById("blueCheck").checked = true;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have more than one item with the id `blueCheck`? What does the HTML for this look like?

Comment: `$('input[name="blueCheckbox"]').is(':checked')` is looking for an item **named** blueCheckbox, `document.getElementById('blueCheck').checked` is looking for an item with the **id** blueCheck. Which is it? You seem to be comparing apples with bananas here...

Comment: none of this has really anything to do with ajax BTW.

Answer (score 3):

On the javascript side you send your data like this:

```
    data: JSON.stringify({ jsonForm: personDetails}),
```

But your Action signature in the Controller is this:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult submitForm(updatePersonDetails personDetails)
```

The default MVC Binder can't bind that together. In the POST your ViewModel is nested in an object with "jsonForm" property, MVC can't match that to the "personDetails" parameter.

You need to either:

1. Change the JSON property name to match the parameter name in your Action:

   ```
   data: JSON.stringify({ personDetails: personDetails})
   ```
2. Or just delete the nested property. For simple POSTs there is no need for that. You can just POST your data like this:

   ```
   data: JSON.stringify(personDetails)
   ```

   I like this solution more because then it doesn't matter what the parameter name in your action is. The MVC will bind the data solely based on the property names in updatePersonDetails class.

Answer (score 2):

Try to execute same code after removing below statement

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

For more information about preventDefault please check below link
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thanks, but it's still returning 'False'. I think my problem might be in the way the code is set up rather than the browser so I'm going to take another look at that

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var blue = $('#blueCheck').is(":checked") ? true : false;
```

Comment: then just check out answer from @LambdaCruiser - also it'd be useful to know whether other values are bound correctly...